# Using HTTP to request an html file, why TCP sequence number not continuous?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

I used wireshark to sniff TCP packets when I access an HTTP html. The first four TCP packets are briefly described as follows. I wonder why in the fourth packet, the sequence number is 1 instead of 2? I think now that the sequence number in the third packet is 1, the fourth should be 2.

```
Src to Dst: 192.168.1.104   128.119.245.12  TCP     Port: 52721 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 
Src to Dst: 128.119.245.12  192.168.1.104   TCP     Port: 80 → 52721 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 
Src to Dst: 192.168.1.104   128.119.245.12  TCP     Port: 52721 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 
Src to Dst: 192.168.1.104   128.119.245.12  HTTP    Port: 52721 GET /wireshark-labs/TCP-wireshark-file1.html HTTP/1.1    Seq=1 Ack=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequence numbers don't count packets; they count bytes, plus the SYN and FIN flags which take one "tick" each of sequence number space, even though they do not appear in the data.

1. .104 sends the SYN flag, with sequence number 0.
2. .12 acknowledges the SYN, and sends its own SYN, also with sequence number 0.
3. .104 acknowledges the SYN from .12. It does not send any data, so its sequence number stays at 1.
4. .104 starts sending data, starting at sequence number 1.

In reality, the sequence numbers have a random offset to make them harder to predict, but Wireshark subtracts this offset before displaying the packets..